# Open location data?

Tags: web, geolocation, location, opendata

Does anyone know where I can get access to some good **location data** for towns / cities / counties etc for the UK or globally?

Hoping to use for auto-completing forms in a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data). You can download geolocation data for the entire planet, or just for some areas.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the [open data portal](http://data.gov.uk/) of the UK.